# Why is ruler not shown in insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I have the `ruler` shown, but as soon as I drop into insert mode, it disappears and reappears upon entering normal mode. This is very annoying when trying to insert a certain number of spaces to have the cursor at column x.
MacVim shows no such behaviour.

How can I show the ruler in insert mode?

Comment: It does show for me in insert mode. Did you try with plugins disabled? Try with an empty vimrc (`vim --noplugin` and `vim -u NONE`).

Comment: `:verbose set ruler?`

Comment: Ok, yes it seems to be plugin related (update: YouCompleteMe is the culprit). Also right now it only happens with program files like `.py` or `.cpp`. `.txt` does not have this issue.

Comment: This questions is seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this working?**"), cannot be reproduced, and doesn't include any vimrc files. It is most likely related to a setting, combination of settings, or a plugin. Please see [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1325/51).